# Select/Insert from identical table on two different DB connections

Tags: select, apache-camel, sql-insert

I have to do a select from a table and insert into another identical(same structure) table on two different DB connections.
This is my code:

```
    from("direct:" + getId)
.toD("sql:classpath:" +getSql1 + "?datasource= DataSourse1&usePlaceHolder=true"))
.setHeaders("Results", simple(${body})
toD("sql:classpath:" +getSql2 + "?datasource= DataSourse2&usePlaceHolder=true"))
```

where 
getSQL1 : Select * FROM Product1
and 
getSQL2 :Insert Into Product2 Values(${headers.results})

It does not work because of the data format I'm trying to insert, I suppose. What I get from the Select is something like this:
[{ID=130, DESCRIPTION=Product130}]
So, I need to clean my data and get only 130, 'Product130'
Any help? Thanks.

Comment: .setHeaders()?  Are you getting exceptions?  Anyway, the data format returned is (by default) Java objects: `List` of `Map`.  It's a List because there's nothing there that prevents multiple records from being returned, and Map for multiple columns.  If you expect one and only one record, you can use the sql uri option `outputType=SelectOne` and that will give you just a Map if you have multiple columns.  I'm not sure how you're externalizing your sql strings there.... Also you don't need .toD() to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your actual code works and you're just transferring one record, change the getSql1 select option part to this:

```
"?datasource= DataSourse1&usePlaceHolder=true&outputType=SelectOne"
```

That puts a map into your message body as a result, instead of List of Map.  No need to copy the result into a header. With Camel's SQL component, it will look for named query parameters in your message body if the body type is a Java Map.

Next change your insert to use the parameters within the Map:

```
insert into Product2 (ID, DESCRIPTION) values (:#ID, :#DESCRIPTION)
```

Notice I included the column names.  This is for safety and good practice.  If by chance the column order isn't the same as the origin table, this will still work.

Comment: I'm transferring more than one record. Just to simplifying, I wrote the select to returned one record. What I get is a List of Map, of course. I was wondering if it was possible to do something like that: Insert into Product2 Select * from Product1 ?

Comment: With the possibility of multiple records returned, I suggest using Camel's Splitter EIP by splitting on the body like this after executing your select: `..split().body().<the insert into I showed above>.end().<whatever else you want to do>...`.  I think that addresses your original question.  As to your new SQL question, it's been asked before here.  Because it uses different databases, the solution is normally database vendor specific. But if the SQL works for your specific database brand, you can (generally) use Camel to execute it.

Comment: I've followed your advice and now works fine. Thanks.